How to Mesh Boolean a collection of objects using Geometry Node
I would like to know how to do a Mesh Boolean of a collection of objects in Geometry Node. Based on the picture, I want to hide those cylinders by placing them on the box, but it has an error "Instances in input geometry are ignored". I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Did you try to Realize Instances on these instances ?

How to do Realize Instances? @Lutzi thanks

I think the issue is the Instances input, unlike Object Info that which is Geometry input.

Shift+A > And type "realize", you should get this node first

It worked! Thank you so much Lutzi
